# What's the transform parameter in b2PolygonShape::TestPoint(p1, p2)?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm very new to box2d and I just want to make a simple check to see if a point is inside a polygon in cocos2d.

```
b2PolygonShape polygon;
b2Vec2 vertices[] =
{ 
    b2Vec2(300, 400),
    b2Vec2(350, 400),
    b2Vec2(300, 500),
    b2Vec2(350, 500)
};

polygon.Set(vertices, 4);
if(polygon.TestPoint(b2Transform(), b2Vec2(301, 405)))
{
    CCLOG(@"Point is inside");
}
```

I dont understand what the first parameter expecting a b2transform. Why is this needed and what should I set it to? Is there something im forgetting? Im trying to do this without doing anything complicated at all like having a worldobject and so on. What's the easiest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool TestPoint(const b2Transform& transform, const b2Vec2& p) const;
```

The transform allows you to specifiy the polygon in local coordinates, and then transform it (translate and rotate) it to its desired position/orientation. If you want want the polygon vertices to be the worldspace coordinates, use an identity (like multiplying with 1) transform:

```
btTransform identity; identity.SetIdentity();
polygon.TestPoint(identity, ...
```

You need to explicity set it to identity, as the default constructor in both b2Transform and its two members b2Vec and b2Rot don't do anything, an therefore will contain random junk in the release build (debug usually sets all un-inted values to 0).

See b2Math.h and b2PolygonShape.cpp for details.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand, I'll try that tomorrow and mark as correct if it works out.